# How to change Mac notifications persistence

Tags: terminal, big-sur

With the older versions of macOS there are two terminal commands to change the persistence of notification banner. You could've done that with some app too, like TinkerTool or Cocktail. With Big Sur those commands no longer work and those optiona are no longer available in any app. Is there a way to do it with Big Sur?

Comment: Are tou searching for something that could be done on Terminal or can I propose something in System Preferences?

Comment: System preferences, sorry, there's nothing in here about it.